# How to clean a list

Tags: python

I have a list like this

```
countries = ["['Luxemburgo ", 'Suiza ', 'Noruega ', 'Irlanda ', 'Islandia ', 'Catar ', 'Singapur ', 'Estados Unidos ', 'Dinamarca ', 'Australia ', 'Suecia ', 'Países Bajos ', 'San Marino ', 'Austria ', 'Finlandia ', 'Alemania ', 'Hong Kong ', 'Bélgica ', 'Canadá ', 'Emiratos Árabes Unidos ', 'Reino Unido ', 'Israel ', 'Nueva Zelanda ', 'Francia ', "Japón ']"]
```

and I don't know how to convert it to a really list. If I print the first element:

```
>>> print(countries[0])
['Luxemburgo
```

How can I do to eliminate the [ and it would have the two '' because it's a string but with the rest of the words in the list that prints only the word without the ''.

Comment: How did ```countries``` end up as a string?

Comment: Ok, how do you get this list in a first place? It seems like you would split by space string representation of list...

Comment: Yes, I have a list from a file. If I open the file I have a list of all the countries(separeted with comas) as an element, I have to make split to can access to each element. How can I do to have it correctly?

Comment: Is it a CSV file? Or a JSON file?

Comment: it's a txt file

Comment: Can you show the code you used to read the file? And a small excerpt from the file?

Comment: countries = list(open('country.txt', 'r'))

Answer (score 1):

The better question is: Where did the list come from and can we fix the problem at the source?

But you can fix it now by doing:

```
import ast
countries_fixed = ast.literal_eval("', '".join(countries))
```

Afterwards, your list elements still contain spaces, to fix that too, you can do this instead:

```
countries_fixed = ast.literal_eval(
    "', '".join(country.strip() for country in countries)
)
```

Result:

```
>>> print(countries[0])
Luxemburgo
```

Comment: What librery must I have? I have "name 'ast' is not defined"

Comment: Ah, you need to import `ast`, sorry about that; I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do like this:

```
countries = ["['Luxemburgo ", 'Suiza ', 'Noruega ', 'Irlanda ', 'Islandia ', 'Catar ', 'Singapur ', 'Estados Unidos ', 'Dinamarca ', 'Australia ', 'Suecia ', 'Países Bajos ', 'San Marino ', 'Austria ', 'Finlandia ', 'Alemania ', 'Hong Kong ', 'Bélgica ', 'Canadá ', 'Emiratos Árabes Unidos ', 'Reino Unido ', 'Israel ', 'Nueva Zelanda ', 'Francia ', "Japón ']"]
lis=[]
for x in countries:
  lis.append(x.replace("['","").replace("']",""))
print(lis[0])
```

output:

> Luxemburgo

Comment: This doesn't work if they have data with a "[" or "]" in it naturally.